# How to push two Arrays(having json objects) into a new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, push

I Want These two arrays into a new array and then i want to print the final array along with all json objects.

```js
var z = [{
  "appId": "1",
  "appName": "CapLogix",
  "envId": "970",
  "envName": "UAT4"
}, {
  "appId": "73",
  "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
  "envId": "971",
  "envName": "UAT4"
}];

var y = [{
  "appId": "1",
  "appName": "CapLogix",
  "envId": "959",
  "envName": "SIT-4"
}, {
  "appId": "73",
  "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
  "envId": "963",
  "envName": "SIT-4"
}];
```

This is what i tried so far

````
z.push(y);

for (var i=0 ; i<=z.length;i++)
{
document.getElementById("sa").innerHTML+="appId  :"  + z[i].appId + "<br>" + " appName  : "+ z[i].appName + "<br>" + "envId  :"  + z[i].envId + "<br>" + " envName  : "+ z[i].envName;
}```
````

Comment: Can you post the code what you have tried so far??

Comment: how will the final array look like?

Comment: same as z array but json objects of y also inside it so the total length of array will 4 after pushing all json objects from array y. @brk

Comment: @brk it will look like this                                                                                                                 [
  {
    "appId": "1",
    "appName": "CapLogix",
    "envId": "970",
    "envName": "UAT4"
  },
  {
    "appId": "73",
    "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
    "envId": "971",
    "envName": "UAT4"
  },
  {
    "appId": "1",
    "appName": "CapLogix",
    "envId": "959",
    "envName": "SIT-4"
  },
  {
    "appId": "73",
    "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
    "envId": "963",
    "envName": "SIT-4"
  }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can make use of **spread operator** (ES6), this will spread all
>   the items of array into new array Example below

```js
const z = [{
  "appId": "1",
  "appName": "CapLogix",
  "envId": "970",
  "envName": "UAT4"
}, {
  "appId": "73",
  "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
  "envId": "971",
  "envName": "UAT4"
}];

const y = [{
  "appId": "1",
  "appName": "CapLogix",
  "envId": "959",
  "envName": "SIT-4"
}, {
  "appId": "73",
  "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
  "envId": "963",
  "envName": "SIT-4"
}];

const finalArray = [...z, ...y];
console.log(finalArray);
```

**If you want to push all values in to first array (z), you can do something like this**

```
z.push(...y);
console.log(z);
```

So you will end up with `z` containing all items of both the arrays

**EDIT**

> you can use `filter` to filter items and get new array, To get the
>   array items which contains **appName: "CapLogix"** (Example below)

After merging array you can apply filter on it.

```js
const z = [{
      "appId": "1",
      "appName": "CapLogix",
      "envId": "970",
      "envName": "UAT4"
    }, {
      "appId": "73",
      "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
      "envId": "971",
      "envName": "UAT4"
    }];

    const y = [{
      "appId": "1",
      "appName": "CapLogix",
      "envId": "959",
      "envName": "SIT-4"
    }, {
      "appId": "73",
      "appName": "ConfigBuilder",
      "envId": "963",
      "envName": "SIT-4"
    }];

z.push(...y);

const filteredArray = z.filter(each => each.appName == 'CapLogix');
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this trick

```
         z.push(...y);

         const filteredArray = z.filter(each => each.appName == 'CapLogix');
          console.log(filteredArray);
```